# Is there a way of calling a data frame within a function using paste0? (Keep in mind the variable is dynamic)

Tags: r

I'm trying to automate some processes for email alerts, therefore I have to call different dataframes with different groups of emails and names. I am not able to call the dataframe using `paste0`, I've run out of ideas, any feedback would be appreciated.

I've gone through a lot of questions but none of them are doing what I want to do.

In the following code, `i`is the previous value for other automated processes.

```
for (u in 1:i) {



for (g in 1:length(Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name)) {



  for (a in 1:length(Merged_table1$`Review ID`)) {

    if (!is.na(paste0("Merged_table",u)[,c(Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name[g])][a])){
      print(paste0(g, a))

      if (paste0("Merged_table",u)[, Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name[g]][a] <= (Sys.Date() + weeks(2)) & paste0("Merged_table",u)[, Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name[g]][a] >= (Sys.Date())){
        newrow <- (c(paste0("Merged_table",u)[["EMAIL"]][a], paste0("Merged_table",u)[a,c(1)], paste0("Merged_table",u)[["Review Category"]][a], Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name[a], as.Date(paste0("Merged_table",u)[, Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name[g]][a],"%Y-%m-%d") ))
        paste0("x",u) <-InsertRow(paste0("x",u), NewRow = newrow)

      }

    } 
  }
}
}
```

> Error in paste0("Merged_table", u)[,
>   Milestone_data$Milestone_Column_Name[g]] :    incorrect number of
>   dimensions.

This is the error I am getting- The optimal result would be to have my three different data frames from the three initial ones that comply with the conditions I've set in the formula.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need the `get`function. Consider this simple example:

```
x_1 <- 11

paste0("x_", 1) * 2
```

> Error in paste0("x_", 1) * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
get(paste0("x_", 1)) * 2
[1] 22
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me! My code is working now.